# Got unauthorized client error while refreshing access token

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Unauthorized client error while calling API https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

```html
$client_id = 'xxx';
$refresh_token='xxx';
$client_secret='xxx';
function GetRefreshedAccessToken($client_id, $refresh_token, $client_secret)
{
    $url_token = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';   
 
 $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&refresh_token='. $refresh_token . '&grant_type=refresh_token';
         
        $ch = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_token);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost); 
 $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); 
        print_r($data);
        exit;
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
 if($http_code != 200) 
        {
  throw new Exception('Error : Failed to refresh access token');
        } 
 return $data;
      
}


add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_application_form');

function save_application_form($wpcf7) {
    
$client_id = 'xxx';
$refresh_token='xxx';
$client_secret='xxx';

global $wpdb;
$wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm :: get_current() ;
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ($submission) {
$submited = array();
$submited['title'] = $wpcf7->title();
$submited['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
$uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
$cf7_file_field_name = 'file-846';
 $image_location = $uploaded_files[$cf7_file_field_name];
 $test = pathinfo($image_location);
 
}

GetRefreshedAccessToken($client_id, $refresh_token, $client_secret);
$token = GetRefreshedAccessToken($client_id, $refresh_token, $client_secret);
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media";
$headers = array(
"Content-Type: image/jpeg",
 "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//$data1 = '@'.realpath('./metadata.json').';type=application/json;charset=UTF-8';
//$data2 = '@'.realpath('./test.csv').';type=text/csv';
$postdata = array(
'file' => file_get_contents($image_location)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$output = curl_exec($ch);   
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $output;
}

}
```

I want to refresh auth token automatically. But I got error unauthorized client error while calling API. Is it possible to upload media file on someones's google drive? For that I need refesh token. So It should not asking login again and again

Comment: Is there anyone to reply?

Comment: Whats $token? comming back as?

Comment: I have added print_r($data); exit; to check data. It gives unauthorized client

Comment: Fine but what is $token = GetRefreshedAccessToken($client_id, $refresh_token, $client_secret);

Comment: It is auth token while uploading file on drive